# Accessing element attributes before Polymer element registration

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-1.0

I'd like to declare attributes *directly* on a Polymer element, which are then passed inside the element and are readable/accessible *outside* of the element script.

I'd like to use the values of such attributes for deciding *how* to register the element.

---

**tl;dr**

I'm having an issue where I need to register an element some time after the whole page has loaded - i.e I want to manually register the element.

#### A solution for registering elements on demand:

```
 <dom-module id="foo-element">
   <template>
     <span> Foo element </span>
   </template>
 </dom-module>

 <script>
  window.addEventListener("app-ready", function() {
    "use strict";

    Polymer({

      is: "foo-element",

      properties: { 
      //..... rest of element properties, methods, etc
```

Explaining what I'm doing above:

- Instead of using `HTMLImports.whenReady(<element-registration-code>)`, I use `addEventListener(event, <element-registration-code>`
- I broadcast `app-ready` when I want the registration to happen
- This allows me to register the element, *on-demand*

#### The reusability problem of the above solution

This poses a severe **reusability problem** - while this element in one of context needs to be registered at some specific point in time, in other context it might not - it should register itself using the standard `HTMLImports.whenReady(<elementCode>)` method.

#### An ideal example:

```
<!-- Registers automatically when `HTMLImports` are ready, the "regular" way-->
<foo-element></foo-element>

<!-- Registers only when it picks up an `app-ready` event-->
<foo-element no-auto-register register-on-event="app-ready"></foo-element>
```

and the element could look something like this:

```
<dom-module id="foo-element">
  <template>
    <span> Foo element </span>
  </template>
</dom-module>

<script>

     // if `no-auto-register` is set on the element, 
     // do not use `HTMLImports.whenReady()` and use 
     // `addEventListener` to register when an event
     // with the value of `register-on-event` property fires.

</script>
```

#### Long story, short

Is there any way to declare a flag/property/attribute directly on the element which would decide how the registration should happen?

Comment: In ES6 example of `polymer` there is a function `beforeRegister` that is triggered before the element is registered, where we declare element's` is` and other properties (which is equivalent to `created` method). Maybe you can achieve it with that. [Here](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/blog/es6.html#defining-polymer-elements-from-a-class) is the code for ES6.

Comment: @a1626  that 'beforeRegister' callback is still *within* the registration lifecycle though so it won't help - tbh I don't think this can be solved in any "Polymeric" kind of way since the registration decision lies outside the Polymer constructor completely

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing an `attribute` to element might not work as element needs to be in `ready` state for that. Below are three ways that might help you with what you are trying

**One way** to `lazy register` your elements in `Polymer` is to use `Polymer.Class` instead of `Polymer` constructor. This way until you register your element manually it will not get rendered. Below is an working example of same.

```html
<base href="https://polygit.org/components/">
<script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
<link rel="import" href="polymer/polymer.html">

<dom-module id="poly-form">
  <template>
    <style></style>
    I am parent Element
    <div>
      <button onclick='register()'>Save</button>
    </div>
    <show-form></show-form>
  </template>
</dom-module>
<script>
  Polymer({
    is: 'poly-form',
  });

  //element to lazy register
  var showForm = Polymer.Class({
    is: 'show-form',
    ready: function() {
      this.textContent = 'I am working...';
    }
  });

  function register() {
    var form = document.querySelector('poly-form');

    //lazy register the element
    document.registerElement('show-form', showForm);
  }
</script>


<poly-form></poly-form>
```

In this example `show-form` element does not render until the button is clicked.

**Note** I've never really tried this with element containing `dom`.

**Second way** this should also be possible with [`importHref`](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/api/Polymer.Base#method-importHref) method.

**Third way** is `global setting` [lazy-register](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/settings) where element gets register only when its first instance is called.

Sorry, the snippet is not as well constructed as it could have been. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks - I think that what I'm after isn't really possible. The alternative ways you listed here are stuff that I already know, unfortunately

Comment: You cannot do it by declaring a Polymer property, but you can try [data-attributes](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp) of HTML5. I've never work with them so don't know if they'll help or not.

Answer (score 0):

[Class Style Constructor](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/registering-elements#element-constructor)

> If you want to set up your custom element's prototype chain but not register it immediately, you can use the Polymer.Class function. Polymer.Class takes the same prototype argument as the Polymer function, and sets up the prototype chain, but does not register the element. Instead it returns a constructor that can be passed to document.registerElement to register your element with the browser, and after which can be used to instantiate new instances of your element via code.
>
> ```
> var MyElement = Polymer.Class({
>
>  is: 'my-element',
>
>  // See below for lifecycle callbacks
>    created: function() {
>       this.textContent = 'My element!';
>    }
>
> });
> document.registerElement('my-element', MyElement);
>
> // Equivalent:
> var el1 = new MyElement();
> var el2 = document.createElement('my-element');
> ```

Comment: I'm aware of this - What I want is a way to declare a property on the element that will decide if an element should be registered automatically, or wait for an event instead.